# How to remove new line from string while reading XML using Python?

Tags: python

I am reading XML using Python and writing CSV. One of XML element has New Line along with the data. So, When I write the CSV new line comes in between data.
I am trying different methods to remove new line while reading XML.

```
for demo in root.iter("CustDemo"):
  dob_imputation = demo.find("dob_imputation").text.replace("\n","")
```

Getting below error:

```
dob_imputation = demo.find("dob_imputation").text.replace("\n","") 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

dob_imputation is a XML element and I am trying to store it in a variable without new line.

Comment: Use backslash `\n`

Comment: dob_imputation = demo.find("dob_imputation").text.replace("\n","")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: what is type(demo)

Comment: It's variable which iterate XML parent element. Question updated.

Comment: get text first then ; `if dob_imputation:dob_imputation.replace("\n","")`